# Highlighting specific parts of a 3D model/object in WebGL/Three.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, 3d, three.js, webgl

Forgive me if I do not explain this very well. I'm hoping to build basic 3D models, more specifically buildings/floor plans, using WebGL. I'm hoping that this will allow me to view the 3D models in a web browser and eventually use Cordova/PhoneGap to package it down into native apps for iOS and Android.

I'm fairly confident that I'll be able to display the 3D models, as I've seen examples that do similar things. However I wish to be able to highlight specific parts of the model when they are searched for. For example, if there were 3 separate rooms in the 3D model of a building, i'd want to be able to highlight one the rooms in red, when the user searched for it.

So in essence I'd need to assign each of part/room in the 3D model a unique identifier, and when the user searches for that unique identifier, highlight the correct room.

The idea is simple, however I do not know if there is any current library that will allow me to do such a thing? I did look briefly at Three.js.

EDIT

The question is, can this be achieved with three.js? And if so, are there any good tutorials or examples that I can use as a starting point?

Comment: So what's the question? Could it be done with Three.js? - Yes.

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is [off topic for stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have edited the question - are there any good tutorials or examples that you could point me to? @mlkn

Comment: It sounds like you need to start with basics. Just start coding. Then hit google or stackoverflow when you run into blockers. When Googling for three.js, look into the basics: setup a scene, lights, renderer, camera, etc. Then define a primitive such as a cube. Add it to the scene. then modify the color of the material on the cube. Then look into ray casting for clicking on it. Then start building a more complex 3d-model and app. The examples folder on the three js website has a huge array of solutions ranging from very simple to very complex and custom: https://threejs.org/examples

Comment: Again, [asking for off site tutorial recommendations or example links is off topic for stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).